# How does the loops and variables in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, loops, variables, jekyll

When I compare in if the post.category is as if there was a post that is the variable is more when I put {{post.category}}  it prints the name. It's like if he did not exist in most if I put in if site.post.category handle all values. The problem is that I want to get the current post to compare if that category. I want to list the posts by category.

```html
<div class="posts">
        {% for post in site.posts %} 
         {% if post.category == Eventos %}
        <hr>
        <div class="post">
            <h1 class="post-title">
              <a href="{{ site.url }}{{post.url}}">
                {{ post.title }} 
              </a>
            </h1>
            <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }} / {{ post.category }}</span> {{ post.excerpt }}
            <h6><a href="{{ site.url }}{{post.url}}">Leia mais...</a></h6>
        </div>

          {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Simply need to filter the category of post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **categories** !

```
{% if post.categories | contains: 'Eventos' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , I managed to solve with `{% if post.category == "Events" %}`